# Fetch include credentials, ask username and password again

Tags: javascript, request, fetch, credentials, ntlm

How can I reset fetch to ask for the username and password again if the server replies with an error code from an incorrect authentication. I'm calling the server like so:

```js
fetch('fooUrl', { credentials: 'include'});
```

Edit: The server is using NTLM as authentication method, so the browser shows a username and password prompt. But if the user inputs incorrect credentials the prompt doesn't show again.
[The prompt is like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms3LL.png)

Comment: Fetch never asks for credentials. So. There is no "reset" concept

Comment: try `fetch('fooUrl', { credentials: true});`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen ... true is not a valid value for credentials. Are you conflating XMLHttpRequests withCredentials?

Comment: You need to append `.then(r => { if (r.status === 401) { ... } });` and proceed accordingly. I.e. send the user to the login page or whatever

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen FSOG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

Comment: @JaromandaX when I use credentials include it pops up a small prompt asking for the user to input username and password (this could be because we're using NTLM on our server), the thing is if the user puts and incorrect password the prompt doesn't show up again so it's impossible to correct it.

Comment: @JaromandaX i was mixing `withCredentials` with `credentials`, my bad